How can I get proxychains to work on Tails in 2024?
My objective is tor --> socks proxy --> destination
Reason for doing this is to access sites that do not like Tor exit nodes. This is all done on Tails. I have tried running this and get the error messages noted below:
root@amnesia:~# proxychains tor-browser
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
/usr/local/lib/run-tor-browser: 50: ENVFILE: parameter not set
root@amnesia:~# sudo proxychains tor-browser
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
/usr/local/lib/run-tor-browser: 50: ENVFILE: parameter not set
root@amnesia:~# sudo proxychains /usr/local/bin/tor-browser
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
/usr/local/lib/run-tor-browser: 50: ENVFILE: parameter not set
root@amnesia:~# proxychains
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
    usage:
        proxychains <prog> [args]
root@amnesia:~#**

My proxychains.conf:
dynamic_chain
proxy_dns 
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000
[ProxyList]
socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
socks5  127.0.0.1 9050

I have only added the socks5 line. I have seen all of the similar questions asked here. None of them answer my question and my question is specifically related to Tails. Any help is appreciated. For starters, am I running the proxychains tor-browser command in the right directory?

You state that your objective is running Tor through a socks proxy, and you need to tweak torrc config for that, no need to use proxychains for it. Also keep in mind that there were glitches as the serving software were behind the proxychains: it works by intercepting the network traffic of the software it proxifies and if a server listener is opened - the reply traffic is affected sometimes. So - fix your torrc and it will use the SOCKS proxy for outgoing connections as you want it, no need to use external tools for that!
